# Do I need a UUID to program for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uuid

Do I need a UUID to program for the iPhone? I was told I need this, how can I get a UUID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a developer certificate from Apple to install your application on an actual iPhone and to post your application to the Apple Store but you don't need a uuid unless the person mistook developer certificate for uuid and used the wrong term. To get the certificate you have to join Apple's developer program.

Comment: You don't *need* a uuid to program for the iPhone... are you trying to serialize a class or something? If you tell us the exact problem you are trying to solve I'm sure that somebody can be much more helpful.

Answer (score 5):

UUID, Universally Unique ID number, or also called UDID, Unique Device ID number, is part of the certification used to sign an application's code to one or more devices.

It is necessary to be able to transfer your application to your iPhone (or iPod Touch) for testing and for Ad Hoc Distribution. You need to enter (and pay $99) Apple's iPhone Developer's Program (individual or company) to get the certificate that enables you to do this. It is common for a developer to request beta testers to provide their UUID's so that the developer can create the certificate/provisioning file which allows the application to work.

The UUID can be found in iTunes when you have your iPhone connected. On the Summary tab, click on "Serial Number" and it should change to "Identifier". The resulting 40 digit hex number can be copied to the clipboard by pressing Command-C (Mac) or CTRL-C (Windows).

Alternatively, you can download [Ad Hoc Helper](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=285691333&mt=8) app from the iTunes AppStore. When you run it, it creates an email which includes your iPhone's identifier in the body.

Note that you can download the iPhone SDK with a [free account](http://developer.apple.com/iphone) and program using the SDK's built-in iPhone simulator.